# Google font changes site svg logotype

Tags: svg, fonts

I have a code in my html in head section

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
```

If you open [the page](http://time.graphics)
you will notice that logotype become smaller.

How to fix, any suggestions? If i remove google font all works fine.

Comment: The logo doesn't change for me, on Chrome or FF.

Comment: you right! hm... maybe i fixed it in some way